# How to change local php settings

Tags: php

My Server API is ISAPI. How can I change the following local PHP settings?

The settings:

```
max_allowed_packet  
wait_timeout  
post_max_size  
upload_max_filesize  
max_execution_time  
max_input_time  
memory_limit
```

Comment: there is no such settings as `max_allowed_packet` and `wait_timeout`, other settings are PHP settings and should be changed via php.ini file

Comment: I deployed my site on a shared server and I don't have access to the php.ini.

Comment: then read http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php about how and what settings can be set outside php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php for all your config needs